# Comprobar si existe una colección o crearla, en MongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Me gustaría crear una colección con algunos campos en un código que se ejecutará automáticamente, pero el código se ejecutará varias veces y me gustaría ver si existe la posibilidad de verificar que la colección ya esté creada y , si es así, solo actualice, lo he logrado pero no puedo entender cómo comprobar si existe la colección:

```
  db.createCollection("newCollection2", {capped :true, autoIndexId : true, size : 6142800, max : 10000})
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

insert:

```
db.newCollection2.insert({name : "XXX"})
```

pero no se como comprobar que exista, y si existe solo actualizarla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar el método [`getCollectionInfos()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionInfos/#db.getCollectionInfos) el cual devuelve una lista con la información de las colecciones de una base de datos. Luego usando el método [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) de los tipo `Array` de Javascript, obtienes el nombre de cada colección.

Una vez que tengas el nombre de todas las colecciones puedes crear una estructura de decisión para saber si es necesario crear una nueva colección o no. Para ello te puedes apoyar en el método [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes) del tipo `Array`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
use <your_db_name>;
const currentCollections = db.getCollectionInfos().map(collection => collection.name);
if(!currentCollection.includes(<collection_name>) {
  db.createCollection(<collection_name>, {capped :true, autoIndexId : true, size : 6142800, max : 10000});
}
db.<collection_name>.insert({name : "XXX"});
```

Donde:

- `<db_name>`: Es el nombre de tu Base de Datos
- `<collection_name>`: Es el nombre de la colección que deseas verificar su existencia.

Como puedes observar, la nueva colección es creada sólo si la misma no existe en la BD.

Otra forma es pasar directamente el nombre de la colección que deseas verificar como parámetro filtro en la llamada el método. Si la colección no existe en la Base de Datos, se devolverá una lista vacía. Tu estructura de decisión tomará el valor del tamaño de la lista devuelta como argumento de decisión.

Por ejemplo:

```js
use <db_name>;
if(!db.getCollectionInfos({name: <collection_name>}).length) {
  db.createCollection(<collection_name>, {capped :true, autoIndexId : true, size : 6142800, max : 10000});
}
db.<collection_name>.insert({name : "XXX"});
```

Como puedes observar simplemente paso como condición la negación del tamaño de la lista obtenida por `getCollectionInfos()`.

Si la colección `<collection_name>` existe en mi base de datos, el tamaño de la lista será 1, la negación de 1 es `false` por lo que se omitirá la creación de la colección (ya que la misma existe).

En caso de que la colección no exista, el tamaño de la lista será 0, la negación de 0 es `true`, por lo tanto se creará la colección.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

Comment: oye Mauricio, tu explicaciones son excelentes, muchisimas gracias, se ve tu dominio del tema....